# How to initialize an array of objects inside of another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a question. How can I initialize my var ingredientes = []; inside of the object "receita"? Is it done like I did? Or do I have to initialize it inside instead of outside?

```
var receitas = [];
var ingredientes = [];



var ingrediente = {
 constructor: function(aNome, aQuantidade){
 this.nome=aNome;
 this.quantidade=aQuantidade;
 }
};

var receita = {
 constructor: function(aTipo, aNome, aTempo, aCusto, aDificuldade, 
 aDescricao, aIngredientes){
 this.nome=aNome;
 this.tipo=aTipo;
 this.tempo=aTempo;
 this.custo=aCusto;
 this.dificuldade=aDificuldade;
 this.descricao=aDescricao;
 this.ingredientes=aIngredientes;
 }
}
```

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Hi Sergiy - The code you have above won't work the way I believe you expect that it will. What I mean is you've incorrectly created what is called constructor functions in your code. Is it your intent to call `new receita(...)` and pass parameters to be assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're actually looking for are classes, try doing this;

```
var receitas = [];
var ingredientes = [];

class Receita {
  constructor(aTipo, aNome, aTempo, aCusto, aDificuldade, aDescricao, aIngredientes) {
    this.nome = aNome;
    this.tipo = aTipo;
    this.tempo = aTempo;
    this.custo = aCusto;
    this.dificuldade = aDificuldade;
    this.descricao = aDescricao;
    this.ingredientes = aIngredientes;
  }
}

class Ingrediente {
  constructor(aNome, aQuantidade) {
    this.nome = aNome;
    this.quantidade = aQuantidade;
  }
}
```

So to add an `ingrediente` to the `ingredientes` array you should do something like this:

```
var newReceita = new receita('Bolo', 'Bolo de fubá');
ingredientes = [
  new ingrediente('Farinha', 300),
  new ingrediente('Ovos', 2)
]
receita.ingredientes = ingredientes;
```

Answer (score -1):

`receita.constructor(...)` will create all the properties within `receita`.

[image]